# PHP Save output to csv file

Tags: php

I have a long list echoed on my screen looks like this:

```
UVVI0287;PMS340C
UVVI0288;PMS242C
```

etc

Here's the code:

```
foreach(glob('./xls/*.*') as $filename){

     $final = preg_replace('%^([^ ]+?)( )(.*)$%', '\1;\3', $bodytag);

     echo $final;

     echo '<br>';

 }
```

Is there a way of saving this output to csv using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this...

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach(glob('./xls/*.*') as $filename){
     $final = preg_replace('%^([^ ]+?)( )(.*)$%', '\1;\3', $bodytag);
     $temp = explode(';',$final);
     fputcsv($fp, $temp);
 }

fclose($fp);
```

Look into [**fputcsv**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$final = "";
foreach(glob('./xls/*.*') as $filename){
  $final .= preg_replace('%^([^ ]+?)( )(.*)$%', '\1;\3', $bodytag)."\r\n";
}
file_put_contents("final.csv",$final);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('output.csv', $final);
```

I'm not really sure as to what exactly you are trying to output. But I might be able to update the answer based on your reply.